# What does this javascript code do?

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

```
y = x?0:0x80
```

From googling the colon seems to be a ternary operator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's right. (The correct name is the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/Conditional_Operator). It is *a* ternary operator, in that it takes three operands, but it's commonly misnamed *the* ternary operator because it's the only JavaScript operator that does so.)

The code is roughly equivalent to this:

```
var y;
if (x) {
    y = 0;
}
else {
    y = 0x80;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the difference between a ternary operator and a conditional operator? Wikipedia calls it a ternary operation for JavaScript: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation.

Comment: @pimvdb: The name "ternary operator" would apply to any operator that takes three operands. It just so happens that the only JavaScript operator that takes three operands is the conditional operator.

Answer (score 1):

It is a ternary operator. It assigns 0 to y if x is true, otherwise it assigns 0x80.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a [ternary operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation), assigning `y` the value of `0` if `x` is `true` or `0x80` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

It translates to:

```
if(x) then
    y=0
else
    y=0x80
```

But is much shorter.

Comment: +1 for answer, -1 for syntax.

Comment: I never promised perfect syntax. I wanted to give the idea, as it was not something I expected anyone to cut and paste my code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes to all of the above, but it is also checking for the existence of x. If x doesn't exist or is `null`, `y = 0x80`.