# What does the question mark mean in this function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's the documentation for this plugin (There's only two functions.)
http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/#documentation

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function load(num) {
        $('#content').load(num +".html");
    }

    $.history.init(function(url) {
        load(url == "" ? "1" : url);
    });

    $('#ajax-links a').live('click', function(e) {
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        url = url.replace(/^.*#/, '');
        $.history.load(url);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Here's the html:

```
<body>
  <h1>jQuery History Plugin Ajax Sample</h1>
  <div id="ajax-links">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#1">load 1.html</a></li>
      <li><a href="#2">load 2.html</a></li>
      <li><a href="#3">load 3.html</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <hr />
  </div>
  <p>[<a href="../">All samples</a>] [<a href="http://github.com/tkyk/jquery-history-plugin">Project home</a>]</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771786/question-mark-in-javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688337/javascript-if-alternative http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322704/javascript-notation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278232/javascript-explanation-of-and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813840/what-does-this-javascript-code-do

Comment: This is basic ternary operator of javascript refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/be21c7hw(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Ternary operator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1788917/693207)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Question mark and colon in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771786/question-mark-and-colon-in-javascript)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
load(url == "" ? "1" : url);
```

The question mark here is a a ternary if operation, Simply put, it is a **short, inline `if` statement**.

Expanded out, the statement would look something like this:

```
if (url == "")
    load("1");
else
    load(url);
```

If the statement before the question mark evaluates to true, then the left-hand side of the colon is used, otherwise (if it is false) the right-hand side is used. You can also nest this, though it isn't always a good idea (for readability).

Comment: Why no braces like Curt's answer?

Comment: @Jarad If there's only one statement to execute in the block, you don't need the `{}`. Any more than one statement to execute and it requires the `{}`

Answer (score 6):

Its shorthand for:

```
If (url == ""){
   load("1");
}
else {
   load(url);
}
```

Ie. If `url` equals `""` then return `"1"`, otherwise, return `url`

In your example, if the `url` equals `""` then, `1.html` will be loaded, otherwise, `url + ".html"` will be loaded

Comment: So those are the return values?  I can read it just like you posted, but can you give me the pseudo code?

Comment: I'm confused, wouldn't the proper syntax be to include the word "return"?

Comment: It's called a ternary operator and is basically a shorthand method for a conditional statement - more info at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation

Answer (score 2):

It is a [ternary operation](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Ternary_operation).