# Changing the color of a text every 3 seconds in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

i got this code but can anyone explain me how it works

```
var text = document.getElementById('film');
text.style.color = (text.style.color == 'red') ? 'White' : 'red';
```

Comment: [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById), [`element.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.style), [Conditional Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)...

Comment: It's using the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to toggle between colors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the question mark mean in this function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023317/what-does-the-question-mark-mean-in-this-function)

Comment: @jbabey thank you for replying
can u explain the use of "?" in script pls

Comment: @user2305126 `?` and `:` mean `then` and  `else`, in the `if statement`, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an alternative of If-else loop. It can be seen like this too.

```
   if(text.style.color == 'red')
       text.style.color = 'White';
   else
       text.style.color = 'red';
```

Answer (score 3):

It finds an html element by its id, then if the color property of its style attribute is red, it switches to white; otherwise it gets red. Pretty self explanatory, and if you couldn't get that, I suggest you look for more learning material about Javascript.

If you want it to change every three seconds, use the [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) function.

Answer (score 1):

The first line gets the DOM node of the element with the given ID (`film` in this case).
The second line gets the `style` object from that node and sets the `color` attribute to either `red` or `white`, depending on the current value.